# Need the number from the comma separated value in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I have captured couple of amounts from screen, and I need to subtract values, but the values taken are like "5,125,584,324.00" and "10243.45" if I try to subtract, the values they cannot be subtracted because they are "," and "." separated, I am not able to figure out how to convert them to number and perform the subtraction.

```
storeText || css=div.textunderline || GR_AccNum 
select || id=ctlWorkflow_FromVoucherList || label=10,000 
store || 10000 || LR_amt 
storeEval  || Number(storedVars['crntBal'])-Number(storedVars['LR_amt']) ||  bal 
echo || ${bal}  ||
```

Can somebody please help me with this, about how do I go about it?

I have tried using :

```
storeEval || storedVars['crntBal'].match(/^\\d+/); || num
```

but this only captures the value upto the first comma(,).

Comment: check with my answer, let me know if you still have any problems

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium IDE, you can do this:

storeEval | var myNum = storedVars['crntBal']; myNum = myNum.replace(/[^\d-]/g, ''); var Final = parseInt(myNum); | V1

And a similar line for the other value, then subtract that number from V1.

Comment: I would just tweak the regex to not remove the decimal place (since that's valid) and he's looking for a float:

Comment: Like this: 
storeEval | var myNum = storedVars['crntBal']; myNum = myNum.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''); var Final = parseFloat(myNum); | V1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract those two numbers then follow the below code it will do that

```
var a="5,125,584,324.00";
var b="10243.45";

var k=a.split(",");
var y=k[0];
for(var i=1;i<k.length;i++)
{
    y=y.concat(k[i]);

}
y=parseInt(y);

b=parseInt(b);

var result=y-b;
alert(result);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xbL6665v/)**

Comment: Thanks Arun, for your valuable time and suggestion, But while using Selenium IDE where am I supposed to add this code?
I am still new to Selenium IDE.

Comment: i did not use  Selenium IDE anytime. so i don't know where did you place this code.so you need to check where you can wight this code. This answer is a javascript solution of your problem.